# Mesos Marathon Slave Failover Time

Tags: mesos, marathon

I've been doing some preliminary HA testing with marathon and can't get the recovery time below 1.5 minutes. As I am running Mesos version  0.22.1, I did not set the checkpoint flag and setting executor_registration_timeout to 10s and 15s does not seem to improve the fail-over time. Are there other parameters that I need to configure in Mesos/Marathon to achieve faster recovery?
Cheers,

Comment: Could you provide the flags you start mesos master and slave?

Comment: Problem seems to be related to 0.22, where slave_ping_timeout=15 and max_slave_ping_timeouts=5 are hardcoded. Kindly, see "Mesos Slave Failover time" email thread in user@mesos.apache.org.  
Cheers,